# Retrieving pictures from phone picture gallery qml / c++ qt creator 5.3

Tags: c++, image, qt, gallery, qml

I've looked all over the internet with now much luck and I'm really not sure which is the best way to go around this.

So I'm just wondering in qt 5.2 to 5.3 is there any default way of viewing the devices default location pictures/gallery?

or is it better to use a c++ back end with QDir and load them in to a list view in the qml front end. If this is the case I have no idea how to load a picture in from the file system to the front end as I tried this before and if I don't declare the pictures in the qrc file then it gives me and error.

Anyone who has any idea of how i should go around this?

Comment: Have you found any solution yet?

Comment: Yeah you have to use java code and the jni c++ wrapper to call the native gallery app and then when you select a picture return the picture location string back to the c++ class and set a QML image component source to the string. I did have a working example but it was done by one of my employees and im not entirely sure how to do it but when i have a simple working example then ill put it on here.